# Different Nuance between Quit Looking (verb-ing) vs Stop Looking (verb-ing)

Tags: word-meaning

I began to wonder what is the different nuance between using "Quit" and "Stop"

> Quit looking at the police officer like that, that's rude.

or

> Stop looking at the police officer like that, that's rude.

Which one that a native English speaker would use or widely used in their daily life ?

Comment: I don't see any difference. But (I might be wrong about this), "quit looking" seems to be used more often in BrE than AmE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In the example you've given, I can't think of any discernable difference.**

However, in other contexts, the words are not interchangeable. When dealing with motion, use *stop*:

> You need to **stop the car!** (not: You need to quit the car!)

When dealing with habit-breaking, *stop* is acceptable, but *quit* is often the better word:

> You need to **quit biting your fingernails.**

When leaving a place of employment, you normally *quit* the job, but you might *stop* working someplace. In other words:

> How are things going at the restaurant?
>
> > Oh, I **quit that job.**

or:

> How are things going at the restaurant?
>
> > Oh, I **stopped working there.**

Such differences in meaning are too numerous to exhaustively list here, but you can learn more by examining a dictionary. Collins is pretty good – see: ***[quit](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/quit)***; ***[stop](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/stop)***.